# Why are the Escape Characters of a String are Printed when Added to a List?

Tags: python

Look at the following code snippet:

```
str_1 = r'example\example'
str_2 =  'example\\example'
print(str_1, str_2)

list_1 = [str_1]
list_2 = [str_2]
print(list_1, list_2)
```

As expected, the output of the first print statement is the following:

> example\example example\example

But why is the output of the second print statement the following?

> ['example\\example'] ['example\\example']

Instead, I expected the following output:

> ['example\example'] ['example\example']

Could anyone explain to me, why Python prints the escape character, when str_1 or str_2 is added to a list? I'm using Jupyter Notebooks 6.0.3 if that could make a difference. Similar results are yielded when I execute the code block above in the Spyder IDE.

Comment: Because when you `print()` a list, you get the `__repr__` of the elements it contains, not their `__str__`

Comment: ... and `__repr__` of string with a backslash will double that backslash, to make the result a syntactically valid Python string literal.